# class A :, class A(object) :, or class A() :

Tags: python, oop

What is the exact difference among these three and when do we use what?

```
class A:
    pass
```

```
class A(object):
    pass
```

or

```
class A():
    pass
```

Comment: There is no functional difference.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Not in Python 3, but in Python2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54867/what-is-the-difference-between-old-style-and-new-style-classes-in-python

Comment: @KlausD. Since Python 2 is EOL, I do not consider it relevant to questions unless specifically asked for or tagged. Leave it to the poor souls like me who have some legacy apps to maintain.

Answer (score 1):

1. 

```py
class A:
    pass
```

It is implicitly subclass of `object` (**as in other cases**). I think it's most prefereable in case you don't inherit from anything (but it can depend on coding standards).

2)

```py
class A(object):
    pass
```

It is most explicit version.

3)

```py
class A():
    pass
```

In this case, as no class passed as parent class, by default it inherits from object.

So from functionality point of view, there is no difference. In Python3, all clasess inherit from `object` (even if it's not explixitly declared).
However, if you are using Python2, you need to pass superclass explicitly in every case.